# Notifications panel disappeared and other issues

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, notifications, samsung-galaxy-s7

Unlocked unrooted Samsung Galaxy S7 running Android 6.0.1. Suddenly started having the following issues after being restarted:

- Notifications panel disappeared both from home screen, and notification bar when expended.
- Notifications bar doesn't show any icons for apps with notifications - just the carrier's name. (However, the phone still vibrates and plays notification sounds when I receive a message for example - the LED also turns on)
- Recents button doesn't do anything (hardware responds, but does nothing).
- Holding down the power button only shows "Power off" and "Restart' -
  no more "Airplane Mode" option.
- After expanding the notifications
  bar, tapping the cogwheel and down arrow in the top right corner does
  nothing.

Things I've tried with no luck:

- Restart
- Power off, then start
- Restart by holding down the power and volume down buttons.
- Reset settings to defaults

Current settings:

- Airplane mode is disabled
- Power saving mode is disabled
- Ultra power saving mode is disabled
- Notifications are enabled
- Notifications on lock screen set to "Show content"

I tried looking into all the settings, but I'm stumped. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Factory reset? Or flash stock rom?

Comment: Same here with me too. Also the double click the home key for the camera shortcut, it's not working either. I've got a note5 with nothing special going on & no recent updates prior to this issue.